# python3 how to convert into what I think is 4 - '\x04'

Tags: python-3.x

I have this '\x04'

How do I convert to ASCII or whatever it is?  I am not a binary expert.  Is this hex? is that hex for 4?

I tried the below:

```
b'\x01'.decode('hex')

print ('\x01'.decode('hex')  )
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

This does not work:

```
~/Documents/workspace/project/ansible$ python3
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> test = b'\x01'.decode('ascii') 
>>> print ("where->", test )
where-> 
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `b` prefix before the string to denote that it represents bytes, and `hex` is not an encoding, for ascii, you'd use `.decode('ascii')`.

Comment: but it prints binary.

Comment: You're getting a binary number like `0b1` as an output from decode?

Comment: I dont not evneteven copy the out but in so becuase does not allow binary

Comment: I think what you put in the edit is working, it's just that some of the first ascii characters are invisible spaces or control characters, for example, the ascii representation of `4` would be hex `34`.